# Show that A is the identity matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix. Show that the system of equations $Ax = b$ has a unique solution $x$ for all choices of vector $b$ if and only if the row reduced form of $A$ is the identity matrix.
Any help please? There is a hint but I am not sure how to use it.

**Hint**: What happens when you row reduce the augmented matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $A$ is in reduced row echelon form, but **not** the Identity Matrix $I_n$. What does $A$ look like then? Plug this into your equation to see why thee might be a unique solution or why there might not.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The system $Ax = b$ will have a unique solution if and only if the row reduced form of $A$ has a pivot in every column.  The system $Ax = b$ will have at least one solution for all choices of vector $b$ if and only if the row reduced form of $A$ has a pivot in every row.